# ActiveMQ over SSL to a .NET client

Tags: .net, ssl, activemq-classic

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect a C# client to an ActiveMQ instance over SSL using the Spring.Messaging.Nms library?  Or if not using NMS then some other library?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible then Spring.Messaging.Nms is the way, yes. I'm just not sure if the ActiveMQ C# code supports SSL yet or not (the broker certainly does).

You might want to ask on the [ActiveMQ User Forum](http://www.nabble.com/ActiveMQ---User-f2356.html) to see when the SSL support will be released for the C# client for ActiveMQ